# What is rate of emission of heat from a body in space?

Tags: thermodynamics, sun

I want to know the answer to the question in the title, I want to see how much heat energy
can a body emit during present in lonely space without any contact of other body.

By knowing this I can understand how much heat the helium atoms losing in the "sun" of our galaxy.

Comment: for the sun, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight#Composition_and_power , look at the appproximate fit of black body radiation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the object is in thermodynamic equilibrium (internally, not with the surroundings), i.e., when it can be characterized by temperature, then the heat emission rate is described by [Stephan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law).

Perhaps relevant: [Stefan–Boltzmann law applied to the human body](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/679165/247642).

Comment: What I don't see clearly covered in that article is that emissivity is generally wavelength dependent.

Answer (score 5):

> What is rate of emission of heat from a body at space ?

It all depends on whether the body has a source of internal heat, and how far it is  from a source of external heat such as a star. The Sun itself obviously emits a huge amount of energy - about $4 \times 10^{26}$ watts - most of it as visible light  or infrared radiation. The earth emits about $1.2 \times 10^{17}$ watts, which is almost the same as the energy it receives from the Sun (there will be a small difference due to natural sources of heat such as volcanoes, human-produced heat and global warming). The Voyager 1 spacecraft emits about 330 watts of heat due its [RTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator) nuclear power source. A comet way out in the [Oort cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oort_cloud) will emit almost no heat at all.